# How to get each value from dynamically created select option value using jquery by using keyup and onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have  input text field and select dropdown which is dynamically created from add more button.
Here i want to get each input value  and select option value which is dynamically created using jquery by using keyup and change value.
Here i am looking for each text value and select option value by keyup and on change each item

Example:

let first input text hi, selected  option is text

second input text lorem ipsum selected is paragraph.

```
Here is working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/2/
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: what you are looking already in fiddle, as form is created from above selection

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just 
include a link to jsFiddle. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; 
consider what would happen if jsFiddle went down in the future! (It would be *terrible,* we know.)